# How to place item center

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a div in the middle of another div, but always left aligns it.
How I do it easily?

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <p>This I want center</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Specify the inner div width and add `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: @ruth Simple Way to do Center is, using CSS, `text-align:center` .

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered with the easiest google search, but the most obvious way is to give them CSS classes and then style them with CSS

```
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Centred</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in CSS

```
  .parent{
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      background-color: red;
    }
    .child{
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

Comment: please don't give the answer which already duplicated. and Just Mark as a Duplicated.

Answer (score -1):

If it's just text you can use:

```
text-align: center;
```

If you want to align the div, give to the div you want to center a margin:auto, but make sure to give it a width first, otherwise it will not work. For example:

```
width: 500px;
margin: auto;
```